# I have a sybase database in a file. How do I determine for which version of sybase it is for?

Tags: sybase-asa

I've been handed a file which appears to me to be a Sybase database file from some older Sybase version. I have d-loaded the latest sybase package from sybase and tried using that to connect to the contents but failed. Can someone suggest to me how to determine which version of sybase (and perhaps even which sybase db product) my file represents?

This is how the beggining of the file looks in a text editor:

> I ě ^şzÚ ÖK n´Ą   ÍĄ YŘ l   f  ˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙ ˙˙˙˙˙˙˙˙WATCOM
>   International Corp., Copyright (c)
>   1987, 1994 WATCOM International Corp.,
>   Copyright (c) 1987, 1994 WATCOM
>   International Corp., Copyright (c)
>   1987, 1994 WATCOM International Corp.,
>   Copyright (c) 1987, 1994 WATCOM
>   International Corp., Copyright (c)
>   1987, 1994 WATCOM International Corp.,
>   Copyright (c) 1987, 1994 WATCOM
>   International Corp., Copyright (c)
>   1987, 1994 WATCOM International Corp.,
>   Copyright (c) 1987, 1994 WATCOM
>   International Corp., Copyright (c)
>   1987, 1994 WATCOM International Corp.,
>   Copyright (c) 1987, 1994 WATCOM
>   International Corp., Copyright (c)
>   1987, 1994 WATCOM International Corp.,
>   Copyright (c) 1987, 1994 WATCOM
>   International Corp., Copyright (c)
>   1987, 1994 WATCOM International Corp.,
>   Copyright (c) 1987, 1994 WATCOM
>   International Corp., Copyright (c)
>   1987, 1994 WATCOM International Corp.,
>   Copyright (c) 1987, 1994 WATCOM
>   International Corp., Copyright (c)
>   1987, 1994 WATCOM International Corp.,
>   Copyright (c) 1987, 1994 WATCOM
>   International Corp., Copyright (c)
>   1987, 1994 WATCOM International Corp.,
>   Copyright (c) 1987, 1994 WATCOM
>   International Corp., Copyright (c)
>   1987, 1994 WATCOM International Corp.,
>   Copyright (c) 1987, 1994 WATCOM
>   International Corp., Copyright (c)
>   1987, 1994 WATCOM International Corp.,
>   Copyright (c) 1987, 1994 WATCOM
>   International Corp., Copyright (c)
>   1987, 1994 WATCOM International Corp.,
>   Copyright (c) 1987, 1994 WATCOM
>   International Corp., Copyright (c)
>   1987, 1994 WATCOM International Corp.,
>   Copyright (c) 1987, 1994 WATCOM
>   International Corp., Copyright (c)
>   1987, 1994 WATCOM International Corp.,
>   Copyright (c) 1987, 1994 WATCOM
>   International Corp., Copyright (c)
>   1987, 1994 WATCOM International Corp.,
>   Copyright (c) 1987, 1994 WATCOM
>   International Corp., Copyright (c)
>   1987, 1994 WATCOM International Corp.,
>   Copyright (c) 1987, 1994 WATCOM
>   International Corp., Copyright (c)
>   1987, BASEN j ‘ 
>   Ă™pGđČžrEđÇšmAę»b4Ô¨~PHŽ
>   j $ ¨ ýŰ ë    HolBASENş
>   omain_name from SYS.SYSDOMAIN where
>   domain_id=SYSCOLUMN.domain_id),
>   nulls,width,scale,pkey,column_id,"default",
>   SYSCOLUMN.remarks from SYS.SYSCOLUMN
>   join SYS.SYSTABLE7€f
>   SYSCOLUMNSVIEW˙create view
>   SYS.SYSCOLUMNS(creator,cname,tname,coltype,nulls,length,
>   syslength,in_primary_key,colno,default_value,remarks)
>   as select(select user_name from
>   SYS.SYSUSERPERM where
>   user_id=SYSTABLE.creator),
>   column_name,table_name, (select d ·
>     NŃ €e SYSUSERPERMSVIEWŁcreate
>   view SYSUSERPERMS as select
>   user_id,user_name,resourceauth,dbaauth,

---

Thanks!

Filip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any database created with any version of SQL Anywhere (or Watcom SQL) up to and including version 9 can be used with a version 9 SA server. If you have a version 10 or 11 server (version 12 is [in beta](http://marketing.ianywhere.com/forms/sqlanywhereinnsbruckbeta?title=Medallion&content_id_display=1065985&navId=78571) right now), you need to unload it and reload it before the version 10/11 server can run it.

Note that SA version 9 will be end-of-life'd in (checks watch) 11 days.

Comment: Thank you - I will download it shortly to make sure it doesn't stop being available.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can download older versions of sybase and try to connect to the given file.